how simullink or find matlab code for the paper with subjectivity From the 3-D finite difference time domain (FDTD) method - PC-SOA
I need to simulation A research And I will add to it Another number of parameters،The article link is below :
[The article link is below] https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1143/JJAP.45.6116/pdf)
Can I be in a certain place find the matlab code Or can someone provide me its code?
Thank you in advance dear ones!
I tried Newton-Raphson's method to solve rate equations and got results, but I have to get results from the method I requested
